# Java Generic : Operator "*" cannot be applied to T,T . Im hard undestand in generic

Tags: java, generics

I have some work in my college, we have to implement generic code following the module that given.

So I'm making a class that only takes `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, and `String`

I watched some youtube videos about generic and quite understood as well, but there is a problem in my code that I can't find the solution anywhere.

**This is my Class:**

```
    public Kubus(T tinggi, T panjang,T lebar ) {

        this.tinggi = tinggi;
        this.panjang = panjang;
        this.lebar = lebar;

    }

    public T getTinggi() {
        return tinggi;
    }

    public T getPanjang() {
        return panjang;
    }

    public T getLebar() {
        return lebar;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "tinggi: " + getTinggi() +
                "  - panjang: " + getPanjang() +
                " - lebar: " + getLebar();
    }

    public T getResultAsLong(){
        T = getPanjang() * getLebar();
    }
}
```

In getResultAslong method it should take Long data type, but I have a problem that the * operand cannot be used. What is the problem ?

Comment: How is T defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a generic class to perform basic arithmetic operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046209/using-a-generic-class-to-perform-basic-arithmetic-operations)

Comment: quick answer: not possible to multiply instances of object; what should the result of multiplying, for example, `"a"` and `"bc"` be?

Comment: the result of of the multiply should be the value of tinggi*panjang*lebar

Comment: @Piro oh i have to make abstract class. is there any otherway that i can use ? a method of Number class that can multiply ?

Comment: I believe your class is a generic class something like `public class Kubus<T>  {` ?  it is better to give these kind of key code so people don't need to guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I would point out is that you can't directly define a class which *only* accepts a specific list of types. You can only bound T, say, to be a subclass of 1 type (or intersection of types).

For the types listed in the question, the only common supertypes of these is `Serializable` and `Object`. You could declare the type variable as:

```
class Kubus<T extends Serializable> { // or Kubus<T>, equivalent to T extends Object
```

but you can then instantiate with any `T` within this bound, e.g. `Kubus<ArrayList<Frobnicator>>`, since `ArrayList` implements `Serializable`. (`Serializable` is also a pretty useless type to bound on, unless you actually want to serialize `Kubus` using built-in serialization. To paraphrase Josh Bloch's advice in *Effective Java*: "don't").

If you want it *only* to accept those types, all you can do is to limit how the class can be constructed, by making the constructor private, and then providing static factory methods for the types you want:

```
private Kubus(T tinggi, T panjang,T lebar ) { ... }

public static Kubus<Integer> ofInteger(Integer tinggi, Integer panjang, Integer lebar ) {
  return new Kubus<>(tinggi, panjang, lebar);
}

public static Kubus<Long> ofLong(Long tinggi, Long panjang, Long lebar ) {
  return new Kubus<>(tinggi, panjang, lebar);
}

// etc for other specific types.
```

You can then create instances with

```
Kubus<Integer> first = Kubus.ofInteger(1, 2, 3);
Kubus<Long> second = Kubus.ofLong(1L, 2L, 3L);
```

It is still valid to write the *type* `Kubus<ArrayList<Frobnicator>>` (or whatever arbitrary type), but you just can't create an instance of it.

```
Kubus<ArrayList<Frobnicator>> whatever = null;
```

---

This actually gives you the opportunity to solve the specific problem that you asked about (*).

The issue is that you can't multiply arbitrary things together. Here, you need some means to convert a "thing" to a `long` in order to multiply it. Casting to `Long` is not a safe choice, because you can't cast, say, an `Integer` or a `String` to a `Long`.

Because you want to restrict `T` to only certain types, you can also provide a converter to do the conversion type-safely.

Such a converter can be modelled using a `ToLongFuntion<T>`: this takes a `T`, and returns a `long`. So, change your constructor to take another parameter:

```
private Kubus(T tinggi, T panjang,T lebar, ToLongFunction<T> converter ) { ... }

public static Kubus<Integer> ofInteger(Integer tinggi, Integer panjang, Integer lebar ) {
  return new Kubus<>(tinggi, panjang, lebar, i -> i.intValue());
}

public static Kubus<Long> ofLong(Long tinggi, Long panjang, Long lebar ) {
  return new Kubus<>(tinggi, panjang, lebar, lng -> lng.longValue());
}

// etc for other specific types.
```

Assign `converter` to a field in the constructor, and then apply in your multiplication method to get the value as a long, which can be multiplied:

```
return converter.applyAsLong(getTinggi())
    * converter.applyAsLong(getPanjang())
    * converter.applyAsLong(getLebar());
```

---

(*) I am not intending to imply that you can only use this `converter` approach with a `private` constructor: you can, of course, make the constructor non-private, and instantiate directly using the constructor. I just suspect that you'd very quickly get tired of the repetition in writing:

```
Kubus<Integer> first = new Kubus<>(1, 2, 3, Integer::longValue);
Kubus<Integer> second = new Kubus<>(1, 2, 3, Integer::longValue);
Kubus<Integer> third = new Kubus<>(1, 2, 3, Integer::longValue);
// ...
```

Comment: Great answer.  With help of overloading, it could be even more concise: just call the factory method `of` and then we can use the same method name for any supported types.   It will be great to add the case for String, which looks like `public static Kubus<String> of(String a, String b, String c) {
  return new Kubus<>(a, b, c, Long::parseLong);
}`

Comment: thx for explaining this to me ... im hard to understand generic because it the first week in university and we have to implement generic .

Comment: @Andy Turner . how do i assignt converter to my constructor field ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform multiplication operation (*) then first you need to cast the values of getPanjang() and getLebar() to any number format then perform multiplication operation.

Comment: ok i tried

1. - Long a = (Long) getPanjang() * (Long) getLebar() * (Long) getTinggi();

Comment: @ZeinIF try `new Kubus<>(1, 2, 3).getResultAsLong()`.

Comment: @AndyTurner  i tried new Kubus<Long>(1,2,3).getResultAsLong(); , the error is Error:(6, 25) java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.Long

Comment: Try it with `<>` instead of `<Long>`

Answer (score 0):

If your `T` type needs to be a number then you could define it with `<T extends Number>` which would ensure you could call `Number.longValue` on any `T`. Unfortunately you specifically state that it might be a `String` (which presumably you want to convert to a `long` in `getResultAsLong`).

You have a few choices:

1. don't use generics. Define an `interface` or an `abstract class` with a `longValue` method and then extend it for the various types you want to support.
2. convert to `long` via `String` with `Long.valueOf(getLabar().toString())`. That essentially converts everything to a string before converting to a long. Not elegant.
3. use `instanceof Number` and `instanceof String` to decide how to covert them to `long`.

Comment: "Don't use generics" is the only appropriate choice here; but I would add that a new interface is unnecessary if you are modelling a cube, because a cube with non-numeric sides doesn't make sense.

Comment: option 1 is not my choiche becuase we have to use generic

im gonna try option 2 and 3 . thx for reply

Comment: @AndyTurner the question mentioned that the type could be a String.