# How to make a 2D array where every next row is the previous row squared in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to make a generic function that takes an array of numbers (integers, doubles or whatever else), and then make a 2D array in which the first row is that array and every next row is the previous one squared. What I made gives me a

> java.lang.object cannot be cast to java.lang.number

even though I put `E extends Number`. I tried the same function using just int and it does what I need it to do.

Where did I make a mistake? Am I using the "E extends Number" wrong?

```
public static<E> void napraviMatricu(E[] niz) {
    int n = niz.length;
    E[][] matrica = (E[][]) new Object[n][n];

    for(int i = 0; i < matrica[0].length; i++)
        matrica[0][i] = niz[i];

    for(int i = 1; i < matrica.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < matrica[i].length; j++)
            matrica[i][j] = matrica[i-1][j] * matrica[i-1][j];

    for(int i = 0; i < matrica.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrica[i]. length; j++)
            System.out.print(matrica[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question for better understanding? Is it java?

Comment: Yes, it is in Java. If I, for example, have an array Integer[] a = {2, 3, 4} I need my program to print this: 
2 3 4 
4 9 16
16 81 256
(every next row is elements of the previous one multiplied by themselves). Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```java
E[][] matrica = (E[][]) new Object[n][n];
```

Do this (`cls` is of type `Class<E>`):

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
E[][] matrica = (E[][]) Array.newInstance(cls, n, n);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

According to this link, Java generics are not designed in a way to perform arithmetic operations. I hope it helps you regarding generic methods and arithmetic operations:
[Using a generic class to perform basic arithmetic operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046209/using-a-generic-class-to-perform-basic-arithmetic-operations)

Comment: "E" because it's a generic method.  Later I need to make an array of integers, doubles, and floats to prove that it can work with all of them.

Comment: According to this link, Java generics are not designed in a way to perform arithmetic operations. I hope it helps you regarding generic methods and arithmetic operations:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046209/using-a-generic-class-to-perform-basic-arithmetic-operations

Comment: That is exactly my problem, it tells me that I can't use * on E. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Neru Welcome!!